# MSSQL Server 2008r2 database restoration issue

Tags: sql-server

Let me explain the issue briefly.

I am using MSSQL server 2008r2 on which there is a existing database with name "portaluser2" i have created one more database with dbname "chandigarh".

I took the back up of database "portaluser2" and tried to restore it to database "chnadigarh" at time of restoration i am getting error, which i have listed below. Kindly keep in mind that i want both my databases online and unning. Kindly assist if anyone have any idea on this.

```
Error: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Restore failed for Server '64.31.20.2,7426'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4042.0+((KJ_SP2_GDR).150326-2110+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'chandigarh' database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4042.0+((KJ_SP2_GDR).150326-2110+)&LinkId=20476
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that you're restoring one database to the other database implies that you want to replace the target database with the source database. If so, then just delete the target database and restore the source database with the appropriate name and location to become the target database. The target database doesn't need to exist beforehand and this is where you're running into trouble.

Comment: i want to keep both the databases on same server?

Comment: is there any other trick to do so?

Comment: What do you mean trick? You want to create a new database from a backup of the old database, so restore the database backup to a new database. The new database doesn't have to exist beforehand. It couldn't be simpler. There's no "trick" involved.

Comment: Let me explain it more briefly mate, 1st db is used by one of my website i have one more website on same server on which i want to use same database both websites should work ?

Comment: Why didn't you say that in your original question? That's a different question altogether. If you want both websites to use the same database then why are you creating a new database?

Comment: i was unable to express my question well. I was also unaware to this if i could use one db for two websites simultaneously. @joeqwerty thanks for sharing.